# Laravel 5.2 Validation unique with where clause doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel-5

I'm working on a ERP using laravel 5.2 
I need to do this:

When the user tries to create a new bank, the program will perform a validation to check that the given business name and the given ABI code are unique. When the validation will be executed, the program will ignore all those records with value of **1** on ***deleted*** column, for both business name and ABI.

The problem is that it's completely ignoring my where clause.
This is the validation rule:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'business_name'   => 'required|max:255|unique:banks,deleted,0',
        'abi'               => 'required|max:5|min:5|unique:banks,deleted,0'
    ]);
```

The columns in the banks table are:

- id
- business_name
- abi
- disabled
- deleted
- // laravel timestamps

If i didn't misunderstood the documentation for Laravel 5.2 this is the correct way to set a where clause in a unique filter...?

Every kind of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you pass as a third parameter is the primary key's value, hence as you don't pass a fourth parameter which identifies the key, it searches for a record with `id`, by default, that has a value of `0`.

So, you need to pass a fourth parameter, this way, it will ignore all the rows with deleted properties that have the value of `1`.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'business_name'   => 'required|max:255|unique:banks,business_name,1,deleted',
    'abi'             => 'required|max:5|min:5|unique:banks,abi,1,deleted'
]);
```

Comment: Still nothing :( it keeps ignoring any record. It lets me add the same record over and over again. No matter the deleted value. I'm getting a little confused... o-O

Comment: Of course nothing :) Because what we check was unique deleted except 1, updated answer, there was a problem with logic, it should check for unique if it is not deleted I guess, right?

Comment: Still not working.. instead i've noticed that it prompts the error that the field has been taken even on brand new records. Which i'm sure they're not in the database

Comment: It works now! So, can you please explain me this piece of witchcraft? We're checking the uniqueness on the banks table (1st param), on the column business_name that has to be unique (2nd param), excluding from the check all values of 1 (3rd param) of the column deleted (4th param)? Did I get it? Am I wrong or the documentation say's something else? O.o

Comment: Yes you are right, exactly the same. It searches for the banks table on the given columns that has to be unique where it excludes the rows that have the deleted property equals to the 1. On the other hand, it looks for both business name and abi properties' uniqueness, without a boundness. For instance, if there is an another record already saved within the database with same business name but something another abi compared to the record that you try to insert, it will throw an error again.

Comment: But this is how it has to be! At least in Italy (in real life) any Bank business name is associated with a unique ABI code. So there can't be any other Bank with different business name but same ABI. And even the opposite it can't be possible

Comment: Probably it is, I have no idea about the bank business in Italy, but now learned it, thanks :)